# When GenerateAssemblyInfo Is False

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-assembly, fileversioninfo

`<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>`

When **GenerateAssemblyInfo** is false, how can we auto increment the assembly file version

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<Version>1.1.0.0</Version>
<Authors>Author Test</Authors>
<Version>1.1.0.0</Version>
<Authors>Author Test</Authors>
<Company>Test Company</Company>
<Product>AssemblyTest DLL</Product>
<AssemblyVersion>1.2.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
<FileVersion>1.3.0.0</FileVersion>
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
</PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: The same it is done in .netframework projects, the [assembly:foo] attributes in AssemblyInfo.cs.  So add [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")], anywhere you like.